# SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: python, google-chrome, parsing

For one project I need to make a steam data parser. I found a ready-made code, but it was written about a year ago and a lot has changed during this time. Unfortunately, the code developer can't help because of his workload.  And I am constantly faced with errors.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Price_DESC&filter=topsellers')
```

pip install selenium

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def find_hrefs(page=r"https://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=_ASC&filter=topsellers", number_of_pagedowns = 20, DEBUG=True):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    browser.get(page)
    time.sleep(1)

    body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

    for _ in range(number_of_pagedowns):
        body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.2)

    hrefs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

    for index, href in enumerate(hrefs):
        hrefs[index] = href.get_attribute("href")

    needed_hrefs = []
    for href in hrefs:
        if href.startswith("https://store.steampowered.com/app/"):
            needed_hrefs.append(href)

    needed_hrefs = set(needed_hrefs)

    if DEBUG:
        for href in needed_hrefs:
            print(href)
        print("Получено ссылок:", len(needed_hrefs))

    return needed_hrefs

href_arr = find_hrefs(number_of_pagedowns=20)
href_arr_without_ads = []
for url in href_arr:
    href_arr_without_ads.append(url)
```

I work in the chrome browser, version 119.0.6045. I have already tried to specify the address of the driver, but then I found out that it is no longer needed.

I also tried the code through the Firefox browser, but there was an error 255. In general, I do not understand how to fix everything.

I need a code that will parse the data: the name of the game, the price of the game, how many reviews, the rating of the game, the publisher, the developer.

As I understand it, this parser first collects all links to games for itself, and then collects information from links to specific games.